# my links are turning in to special characters

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am working on one application and in that they used **reg as a name**.
here i got the problem i had the link like this for example
http://test.com?fname=#attributes.fname#**&reg**=#attributes.reg#

but when trying to click that link the url variable **&reg** turns in to special character and not able to solve this.

How i will make link not to turn **&reg** in to special character.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

inside an href, Ampersand should be html encoded and the URL params should be URL encoded, transform the & into an entity

```
http://test.com?fname=#urlEncodedFormat(attributes.fname)#&amp;reg=#urlEncodedFormat(attributes.reg)#
```

should do

[w3 html recommendation about URIs in links](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2)

Comment: That's not URL encoded, that's HTML encoded. The params should be URL Encoded. I will edit.

Comment: I hope I didn't come across as snippy.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to put the reg parameter first in the query string so there's no need for an ampersand and no confusion:

```
"http://test.com?reg=#urlEncodedFormat(attributes.reg)#&fname=#urlEncodedFormat(attributes.fname)#"
```

This will also work better if the link is part of editable content stored in a database. If you use an encoded ampersand, it will very likely be rendered back as non-encoded in the edit form text box. That means you will have to remember to re-encode it every time you make a change to the content.